# Calculating number of ways for a seating arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**

if 6 boys and 6 girls sit along a line alternately in x ways and along a circle alternately in y ways then relation btw x and y.

Obviously i searched the internet first. The answer given was x=12y but i am not satisfied the reason it gave me . (the same reason is given at the back of my book )
It said number of ways of seating (in a line) x=$2*6!$ and y= $5!*6!$

therefore x=12y

**My way**

first i took all women out . Number of arranging all men =6!
Now btw 6 men there are 7 gaps .So select 6 seats =7 ways . Now permute women = 7*6!
therefore x=$7*6!*7$ 
my y =$5!*6!$

And hence ,
my relation is  x=42y

Am i commiting a mistake?If so where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a few mistakes. First, the correct answer is $x = 2 \cdot 6! \cdot 6!$, because we can either start with a man or a woman, and then order both the series of men and women separately. Second, your approach of selecting seats is wrong, in that by selecting six out of seven seats, it is possible not to choose a seat inbetween, making two men sit next to each other. Third, you seem to overcount the ordering of women, because one way or the other, six women can only be ordered in $6!$ ways. Overall, you should find:

$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{2 \cdot 6! \cdot 6!}{5! \cdot 6!} = \frac{2 \cdot 6 \cdot 5! \cdot 6!}{5! \cdot 6!} = 12$$